# Ajax call in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i have an issue with the ajax call . Indeed i'm programing a website in php (cakephp framework) and when a popup appear the user have to choose between yes or no button, and depending on his choice i'm saving his choice . But I don't know why it doesn't work.

here's my code : the view (suivis.ctp)

```
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
$(function() {

  // yes = 1, no = 0
  function recordClick(val) {
    console.log('sending...');

    // return ajax call, which returns a Promise object
    return  $.ajax({
      url: 'controller/method',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {the_value: val},
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Data was sent!');
      }
    });
  }

  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

      "Oui": function() {
        recordClick(1).then(function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        });
      },

      "Non": function() {
        recordClick(0).then(function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
</script>


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation de paiement">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Avez vous effectué le paiement ? </p>
</div>
```

the recordClick(0) doesn't work i can't close the pop up with it and i don't understand why. Also my URL is maybe wrong...

and here's my controller : AccountsController.php

```
public function suivis()
{
           if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $value_to_save = $this->request->data['the_value'];

    if ($value_to_save == 1) {
       $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Accounts','action'=>'commander')); 
      $this->Commande->addsave('yes');
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Accounts','action'=>'commander'));
      $this->Commande->addsave('no');
    }
  }
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: `url: 'controller/method',` that's relative to the current url - i.e. it's not fixed and one potential direct cause of why your code doesn't work.

Comment: yeah i guessed so but i tried various URL, how do we "compose" the URL ? knowing that the request has to be sent to the AccountsController.php file (suivis function )

Comment: `'/controller/method'` by default. If it works you're issuing a redirect - which won't do anything. What exactly does "doesn't work" mean - what are you expecting the code to do, what does happen? Please look at the console for js errors, and the network tab of your developer tools to see what your ajax request is doing.

Comment: doesn't work mean that the code doesn't do anything like i explained below in my js part with the button if we click on "yes" val should equal to 1 and 0 if it's no but the function recordClick isn't "called" . what should happen : first the pop up should be closed and then the value of val should be send to the controller and saved and nothing happened. I'm sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: "doesn't do anything" doesn't clarify ... anything. is the code called? is it generating errors? Is the code loaded at all? Please **do not write comments**, [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38433076/edit) to add information. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting not found error in your ajax request due to invalid relative url path.

In your layout file
Add below line under head tag

```
<base href="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>">
```

base tag is helpful in reference path in url. This is works for *url: 'controller/method'* in ajax also. Refere https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your js:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'AccountsController.php',
      data: {val: val},
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Data was sent!');
      }
    });
```

and your php, the the value using:

```
echo ( $_GET['val'] );
```

Comment: Please do not answer a question if you are not familiar with the moving parts. `url: 'AccountsController.php',` No version of Cakephp has urls like that. -1.

Comment: I was just trying to help @AD7six

Comment: It's not working either , Did I have to keep the recordClik function ? and with the echo what did i receive because i don't know what variable i'll use to save after ?